# tail file from remote server and nslookup on local

Tags: shell, shell-script, ssh, remote

I need a script for resolve hosts.

For now I run this script on local machine

```
for i in `tail -F access.log | awk '{print $8}' | awk '{gsub("http://|/.*","")}2' | awk '{gsub("http://|:.*","")}1' | grep -E -v "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"`
do 
   nslookup $i [dns-server_ip]; 
done > ips.txt
```

But i need **tail** file from some remote hosts and run **nslookup** on my local-machine and i don't have a clue how to do it.

Comment: back quote should be replace by $( ) , also it look way to many awk and grep a signle awk command should do.

Comment: Thank you! im not so good in regexp but im looking into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ssh?

Most commands can be executed remotely by just prepending the `ssh` command, so replace `tail -F access.log` with `ssh REMOTEHOST tail -F access.log`
==>

```
ssh myUSER@myREMOTEHOST tail -F access.log |
awk '{print $8}' |
awk '{gsub("http://|/.*","")}2' | awk '{gsub("http://|:.*","")}1' |
grep -E -v "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3})[0-9]{1,3}" | while read i ;
do 
   nslookup $i $dnsServerIP; 
done > ips.txt
```

As @kasperd and @archemar also hinted, you could/should clean up that long pipeline. Here is my take:

```
ssh myUSER@myREMOTEHOST tail -F access.log |
awk '{$0=$8; gsub("https?://|[/:].*","")} !/([0-9]{1,3}.){1,3}[0-9]{1,3}/' |
while read i ; do
    nslookup $i $dnsServerIP; 
done > ips.txt
```

Explanation:

- `$0=$8`. In your example output, the column with the URL you want is #8. This command overwrites `$0` (the entire line) with only element `$8`, effectively throwing away the rest. This replaces `'{print $8}'`
- `gsub("https?://|[/:].*","")}` replaces both of your gsub-calls with one covering all possibilities in one. In your code you also searched for "http://" twice, and did not match http**s**.
- `!/([0-9]{1,3}.){1,3}[0-9]{1,3}/'` replaces your separate grep call while using the exact same regex. It evaluates to true, when `$0` is not a numeric IP, and will this implicitly `{print $0}'`. Slightly shorter `h=$0;gsub(/[0-9.]/,"",h)} h` has the same effect.

Note: The trailing `2` and `1` behind the `}` behind your `gsub`-calls evaluate to `true`, which in turn gets implicitly expanded to `true {print $0}`. This is how/why the last regex in my solution prints the non-matching line implicitly.